# ASP Order By Multifile query

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

I need help to understand if this is possible and how can I do it. 
I Have two asp files, one with the page layout the visible part (default.asp) and the other with the queries (process.asp). In the default.asp I have a table that is populated with information form a query on process.asp. For that to work as soon as you open the page I have the:

```
<!--#include file="process.asp"-->
```

at the beginning. I want to order the table with a click on the column name, so I'm using:

```
<td onclick="document.location.href('default.asp?ord=num')">Number</td>
```

on the default.asp.

How can I pass the information to `process.asp` to use in the `ORDER BY '" & Request.QueryString("ord")ASC"'`

Is this possible.

I'm no developer so sorry if its a dumb question.

Comment: Yes. It is possible but prone to SQL injection attacks (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Have you tried it?

Comment: Also, `document.location.href` is not a function. You probably meant `onclick="document.location.href = 'default.asp?ord=num';"`

Comment: Haim770, thanks for the comment. The onclick is working de way i've posted. Was it not supposed to???

Comment: Are you able to use other tools like JQuery or do you have to do this sorting via page postbacks?

Comment: i have page postback...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay - after re-reading...

Because you've `include`d your file...

```
<!--#include file="process.asp"-->
```

...it is really simply a part of the larger `default.asp` - the `process.asp` file get's merged into the `default.asp` file at the point of the `#include` statement.  To that end, posting back to the same page (as you have) will pass in the `QueryString` value `ord`...

```html
<td onclick="document.location.href='default.asp?ord=num';">Number</td>
```

Once your page starts again (`default.asp`) you can simply read the value in as you specified above:

```vbs
"...ORDER BY " & Request.QueryString("ord") & " ASC"
```

Notice that I've added an extra `&` to concatenate the `" ASC"` and removed the apostrophes `'`.

It is very important that you check this value prior to using it, however.  For instance...

```vbs
Const validFields = " num myfield1 myfield2 myfield3 myfield4 "
Dim ord
ord = Request.QueryString("ord")
If Instr(validFields, ord) > 0 Then sqlString = sqlString & " ORDER BY " & ord & " ASC "
```

...otherwise I can simply use injection to do nasty things to your database (see Haim770's advice above).

Hope this makes sense to you!

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Butt if i use this method i will have another input fild where wi'll be forced to write the colum which i want to order by, right?

Comment: Sorry Hugo, I've completely misread the question.  Excuse my drivel above - I'll edit the answer...